# Using vim to wrap git commit messages

Tags: git, vim

I am having some issues getting vim to wrap my git commit messages.I have tried a few ways to do this referencing posts on here with no success. I am using posh git and have vim set as my core editor. I have also tried various additions to my vimrc file with no success.

To test after each addition to my vimrc file I make a really long commit and then check my log but it is not being wrapped at all. I assume I am doing something wrong as the additions to the vimrc seem to work for other people on here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Additions to vimrc which I have tried

- filetype on (assuming it would use the gitcommit vims formatting)
- au FileType gitcommit set tw=72
- autocmd Filetype gitcommit spell textwidth=72

Comment: `filetype plugin on`.  Then you can modify `tw` by setting it in a file `after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`.

Comment: Hi Sato, should I remove my other commands and just use this one?

Comment: Yeah, actually the other commands have no effect in your setup.

Comment: Thanks Sato I will remove them and try your command. Nos with regards to the set fo+t command do I add that to my vimrc file and what does that do exactly. Sorry to be a pain, only started on vim today

Comment: Hi Sato, thank you for your effort but it looks like I'm not going to have any luck today. I have edited my vimrc and added your command, that looks perfect as both the filetype and on are highlighting as keywords. I then navigated to my program files as you suggested and in ftplugin there is a gitcommit vim which is of type plugin and inside it does set tw to 72, but still no joy. When I open powershell and commit using vim the title is highlighted after 50 but nothing on the body of the commit. If I go over 72 the git log does not wrap.Very disappointing, thanks again though.

Answer (score 4):

Vim does not auto wrap paragraphs by default, you need to do this manually via:

```
gqip
```

If you want to have Vim to do hard-wrapping than you can do:

```
:set formatoptions+=w
```

Vim can also do soft-wrapping (aka Word-like), but that's not what you want obviously.

*Pro tip*: If you want to paste or enter some non-wrapped text (e.g. code example), do `:set paste`, when you finish do `:set nopaste`.

More info:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_word_wrapping
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/80_character_line_wrap_without_broken_words

Comment: Hi Izap, thank you for the reply, I had given up and moved back to notepad. I will give this a try first thing tomorrow and report back. Also thank you for the links.